# How to define a PFRelation on MongoLab, like the way it was on Parse?

Tags: swift, mlab, parse-server

I have a parse-server on Heroku, configured with MongoLab as an add-on.
I can connect now with the client, and even retrieve an array of PFObjects.

I have 2 documents on MongoLab: `Recipe` and `Ingredient`. 
My problem is how I define a PFRelation on MongoLab (like the way it was on Parse BaaS). I don't want to modify client code too much.

I saw that MongoLab, can use a one to many relation with embedded documents or document references. I tried out both, but every time I got this error: 
`[Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)`

Here is an attempt with embeded documents:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56c581f3e4b07bf05b29fac6"
    },
   "name": "Banana pancake",
   "steps": [
       "Mix",
       "Cook"
   ],
   "ingredients": [
        {
            "category": "Diary and eggs",
            "name": "eggs",
            "quantity": "3",
            "unit": "pc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my swift code:

```
 menuRecipes.map {
  $0.ingredients.query().findObjectsInBackground(). .....
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse server handles relations in the same way as parse.com. However native mongo relations are not supported. You have to setup those relations manually in the database for now and this is error-prone. That said, it could be done something like this:

```
"ingredients": [{
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Ingredient",
    "objectId": "tnYLlRXChj",
    "category": "Diary and eggs",
    "name": "eggs",
    "quantity": "3",
    "unit": "pc"
}]
```

Also make sure in your `_SCHEMA` collection that the `Recipe` document has the field `ingredients` set to `array`.